# The best way to get images from a webpage to display on a android app image view?

Tags: php, android, html

Im stuck and out of ideas. Does anyone know the easiest way of getting a image from a webpage and using it on your android app. Help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `Picasso` allows for hassle-free image loading in your application—often in one line of code.

   ```
   Picasso.with(context).load("http://i.imgur.com/DvpvklR.png").into(imageView);
   ```
2. `Glide`, An image loading and caching library for Android focused on smooth scrolling.

   ```
   Glide.with(this).load("http://i.imgur.com/DvpvklR.png").into(imageView);
   ```

Comment: Is there a way to get multiple images from a php page and input them into a image array?

Answer (score 1):

I prefer [Picasso.](http://square.github.io/picasso/)  Once you have the library its really easy to pull images from anywhere online and include it into the app.  [Here's](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android-sdk-working-with-picasso--cms-22149) an easy to follow guide on setting it up to put an image from online into an imageview in your app.
Good luck

P.S.
This could be found within seconds of searching on Google.